# Python: MapPlotting - Overlay points over Georeferenced Image

Tags: python, mapping, projection, wgs84, utm

I have a Georeferenced TIFF file (UTM / WGS84) and some points in the (x,y) format also in the same projection. What I wish to do is plot the image, and then overlay the points on it. Any hints?